# What is an ordinal value of a String?

Tags: php

I'm confused about the term **Ordinal value** of a character or a string in php documentation.
Can somebody tell me what exactly an ordinal value is?

Comment: First hit on Google for "php character ordinal" - http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php

Comment: From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) on ord(), Returns the ASCII value of the first character of string. Which part is unclear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One "character" in PHP is one *byte*. Note that this is misleading for *multi-byte characters*, in which one character (say "漢") is encoded in multiple bytes. Anyway though, a byte is 8 bits and can represent a *number* between 0 and 255. The ordinal value of a <strike>character</strike> byte is simply this numerical value.

```
ord('a') -> 97
```

Read http://kunststube.net/encoding if you need more background information about bytes/characters/encodings.

Comment: @deceze do you know some good tutorial / book for extensive guide to data encoding?

Comment: @Shushant Not beyond what I already linked to.

Comment: i have already read that article it was very helpful to me but i am looking for more article i have already google but it didn't help me out

Comment: unicode equivalent of ord() is IntlChar::ord()

Answer (score 2):

Ordinal value is Nothing but the ASCII value of a character
And as we know every character takes one byte i.e. 8 bits
and every bit can have either 0 or 1 as the possible value
so every bit can have 2 values thus 8 positions can have power(2,8) = 256 combinations
and every combination resembles 1 character like

00000000 => Null(0)

00010000 => Space(32)

(65 - 91) in Ascii => a-z

(97 - 122) in Ascii => (A-Z)

and (48 - 57) in Ascii => (0 - 9)

other combinations are assigned to other special chacater.

PHP have an inbuilt Function ord('a') which takes character as an argument and returns its ascii value i.e. 65 in this case

Comment: Don't conflate characters and bytes here. `ord` just gives you the decimal value of a byte, which doesn't necessarily have much to do if anything with ASCII or characters.

Answer (score 0):

The Ordinal Value of a character is nothing but the numeric location of a character.

Comment: Does that mean the exact position of a character inside a String?

Comment: @SurajAdhikariCsitOriento no it doesn't. The numeric value of ASCII "A" is 65 wherever it is in a string.