# String not found although it should

Tags: php, strpos

```
$row['solved']= "12|10|3";
$id=10;
$pos = strpos($row['solved'], $id);
if ($pos !== false){
    echo "String found!";       
    exit;
}
echo "String not found!";
```

Why does this always return "String not found"?

Comment: ["If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character."](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-parameters)

Comment: @Rizier123 not really...

Comment: @sjagr This should really be an answer, and not a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-parameters):

> If `needle` is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character.

Your `$id` argument is an integer, and accordingly used as an [ordinal value of the character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174563/what-is-an-ordinal-value-of-a-string) (generally the ASCII value.) In this scenario, the ASCII value `10` is representative of the `\n` linefeed character, so you are searching `$row['solved']` for this, which in this particular `$row['solved']` value will be not found.

To fix this, use:

```
$pos = strpos($row['solved'], (string)$id);
```

Comment: I'd upvote this if it explained the significance in a way that a newbie would understand.

Comment: @MarkusK96 In 10 minutes you can accept it, that's plenty enough. Cheers :)