# stripos return false on number comparison

Tags: php, string-comparison, stripos

I have created a common function which check whether the given string exist in string or not. The function was working fine unless i reached to this problem. The problem is if i pass both find and string to 3 i.e int then it is returning false. I believe it should return true. I read on php official site and found this:

> If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character.

Is there any solution to this.

My function is as below:

```
private static function compareValue($string, $find) {
    if (strpos($find, '!') === 0) {
        //removing first ! for comparison
        $find = substr($find, 1);
        //comparison will be like not equals to
        return !(stripos($string, $find) !== false);
    } else {
        return (stripos($string, $find) !== false);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

if is call function like `self::compareValue(3,3)` then it should return true instead false.

Comment: just make sure they are always string `$string + ""` and `$find + ""`

Comment: When it says *ordinal value of a character* - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174563/what-is-an-ordinal-value-of-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [cast to string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) yourself:

```
(string)$find
```

Feel free to add any check that makes sense for you, since blind casting is not a good idea:

```
$find = true;
var_dump((string)$find);
```

```
string(1) "1"
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, stripos is for strings so you should be casting the integer to a string.
Notice that you only need to cast it in the else statement as if it falls under the first condition it is already a string.

```
private static function compareValue($string, $find) {
    if (strpos($find, '!') === 0) {
        //removing first ! for comparison
        $find = substr($find, 1);
        //comparison will be like not equals to
        return !(stripos($string, $find) !== false);
    } else {
        return (stripos($string, (string)$find) !== false);
    }
}
```