# What if the 'needle' parameter of strpos() function contains a converted integer value that can not be applied as the ordinal value of any character?

Tags: php, string, strpos, string-search, ordinals

I'm using **PHP 7.2.8** on my machine running on **Windows 10 Operating System**.

I come across the following text from the [description of 'needle' parameter in strpos() function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-parameters) given in the PHP Manual :

> **needle**
>   If **needle** is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character.

From the above statement about the **'needle'** parameter I don't understand how does the function `strpos();` work when the 'needle' parameter of strpos() function contains a converted integer value that can not be applied as the ordinal value of any character.

Can someone please explain the actual meaning of the statement from the manual when the 'needle' parameter of strpos() function contains a converted integer value that can not be applied as the ordinal value of any character in an easy to understand, simple and lucid language?

It would be better for me and other learning people if you could provide couple of suitable working code examples of `strpos()` function where the 'needle' parameter of strpos() function contains a converted integer value that can not be applied as the ordinal value of any character.

Thank You.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174563/what-is-an-ordinal-value-of-a-string

Comment: @trincot: Please remove duplicate mark from my question. I've already referred the question you have given link of. You can see in the answer of that question there are no more working code examples demonstrating how does strpos() function work when a non-string value is given as a parameter of 'needle'. Mainly, I want to understand that thing. Thank You.

Comment: The question referred to has the right answer. Ask yourself: What does `ord("A")` return? What does `strpos("CBA", ord("A"))` return? What does `strpos("CBA", 65)` return? ...etc.

Comment: @trincot : Suppose, if I give some value which evaluates to a decimal value greater than 255 after the conversion then which cardinal value will be used and how the function would work? That's my actual question. So, can you demonstrate this with some suitable working code example?

Comment: I can see a little room for treating this as a separate question, but then you should update it to distinguish it, as as it is formulated now it is duplicate. If your actual question is about a value greater than 255 then you should ask that, and leave out anything that is unrelated to that specific question. So don't ask what is an ordinal value (like you do now) as that clearly is duplicate.

Comment: @trincot : I've completely changed and modified my question. Now you please remove the duplicate mark on my question. Thank You.

Comment: The actual answer is that any value (within reason) given as `needle` will be converted to `char` (the datatype internally in C, which is one byte in size). The conversion will wrap around (i.e. only the 8 least significant bits will be kept), meaning that `var_dump(strpos('foo', ord('o')+256));` will give `1` as the answer, the same as `var_dump(strpos('foo', ord('o')));`. If you ask the question again, or this question is re-opened, I'll give proper references.

Comment: `ord`  returns the decimal value of the first byte of the character. So if it is greater than 255, it will return the first byte value (between 0-255). You can test this by doing code like `print_r(chr(ord("€")));` Notice that it outputs `â`, because `ord("€")` evaluates to 226, and `chr(226)` returns  `â`.

Comment: @MatsLindh - Interesting... notice that `var_dump(strpos('€fo', ord('€')+256));` returns `0` as expected, but `var_dump(strpos('â€fo', ord('€')+256));` returns `2` So having two >255 characters seems to throw it off.

Comment: And just to be clear, the same result is given when a proper string is provided to `strpos`, meaning `strpos` is always doing the ordinal number conversion, even when a string is provided for the needle : `var_dump(strpos('â€fo', '€'));` returns `int(2)` instead of `int(1)`, same as passing an integer as the needle.

Comment: You're confusing multibyte characters with doing anything special - they do not. `strpos` only consider single bytes, and not the characters themselves. Since you have a multibyte UTF codepoint as the first letter in your second example, there are two bytes in front of the eurosign, giving `2` as the answer.

Comment: @MatsLindh - I'm not confusing anything. I'm saying `strpos` will not give a reliable answer with multibyte strings. If it were simple meant to give the byte position, it would be called `bytepos`. Clearly if someone had a multibyte string and needed to know the position of the first `€` (needing the proper position of that character, not just testing for if it exists within the string), `strpos` would not provide that position reliably.

Comment: Or are you saying that knowing that there are 2 bytes in front of the euro sign is more valuable (for truncation purposes, etc) than knowing that there is one character in front of it?

Comment: That's correct. None of the native PHP string functions work with multibyte strings. They're all used for accessing single byte width string encodings (i.e. they don't know what characters _actually_ are, they just compare byte values). Knowing that there are two bytes in front of € is useful to extract subset of bytes, etc. - these functions are also used for working with bytes directly (and not thinking of them as strings). The `mbstring` module has `mb_strpos` for working with multibyte string encodings.

Comment: Question reopened after revision. @MatsLindh, as you were the first to give the right clues, please be informed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any value (within reason) given as needle [will be converted to char](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/8d3f8ca12a0b00f2a74a27424790222536235502/ext/standard/string.c#L1818) (the datatype internally in C, which is one byte in size). The relevant code from the current strpos implementation:

```
/* {{{ php_needle_char
 */
static int php_needle_char(zval *needle, char *target)
{
    switch (Z_TYPE_P(needle)) {
        case IS_LONG:
            *target = (char)Z_LVAL_P(needle);
            return SUCCESS;
        case IS_NULL:
        case IS_FALSE:
            *target = '\0';
            return SUCCESS;
        case IS_TRUE:
            *target = '\1';
            return SUCCESS;
        case IS_DOUBLE:
            *target = (char)(int)Z_DVAL_P(needle);
            return SUCCESS;
        case IS_OBJECT:
            *target = (char) zval_get_long(needle);
            return SUCCESS;
        default:
            php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "needle is not a string or an integer");
            return FAILURE;
    }
}
/* }}} */
```

That `(char)` cast will wrap around (i.e. only the 8 least significant bits will be kept), meaning that `var_dump(strpos('foo', ord('o') + 256));` will give 1 as the answer, the same as `var_dump(strpos('foo', ord('o')));`.

Be aware that any of the old str* functions in PHP is *not* multi byte encoding aware - they only work on single bytes. A string in PHP is a collection of bytes (and not characters), and calling `strpos` will result in only a single byte value being matched. So if you give it a string with a multibyte encoding, your results will not make much sense.

If you're using a multibyte encoding, such as utf-8, the `mbstring` module provides copies of most of the internal string functions while handling multibyte encoding. For `strpos` [that function is named `mb_strpos`](https://secure.php.net/mb_strpos).

PHP also supported functionality to override the internal function names with their `mb_*` counterparts, but that behavior has been deprecated as far as I remember - and should not be relied on in any manner, since it breaks code in non-apparent ways.